# SOQL & Tests : SetFixedSearchResults() or SOQL?

Tags: soql, unit-test

I'm 'new' on APEX and Salesforce (about a month of training),
I tried to find by my own but can't really find answers ;

I understand that when performing **tests**, SOQL queries aren't really interrogating the database : that's why we use **test.setFixedSearchResults()**

But in another hand, I find codes like [this one](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_testsetup_using.htm)...
What is exactly to understand ?

Thanks by advance for your explanations,
And sorry for my english mistakes

Al

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Test.setFixedSearchResults()` is for testing **SOSL**, the free-text search query language, rather than **SOQL**, the SQL-equivalent query language.

When testing code that makes SOQL queries, your test class (particularly in a `@testSetup` method, which is best practice) is responsible for creating and inserting data that SOQL will return in test context. When you're testing, your code cannot see the real data in your database*, so you programmatically create and insert those records to exert control over what the code you're testing sees and works with.

The Salesforce Developer blog is running a series of articles on testing right now. You might particularly find [part 2](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/month-of-testing-apex-testing-in-depth-part-2-of-3.html) interesting, as it demonstrates how to do this process of creating and using test data.

SOSL queries work differently in test context; they always return a blank result set unless you use `Test.setFixedSearchResults()` to provide test data (rather than inserting test records in the database). See [Adding SOSL Queries to Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_SOSL.htm) for more on testing SOSL.

* this is true unless the `seeAllData = true` annotation is present. Using `seeAllData = true` is *very* bad testing practice and should never be used on new test classes.